# Markov Chain Reach One State Before Another

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm stumped on a problem.  Here's my transition matrix:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{3}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&0&0&0&0&0 \\\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&0&0&0&0 \\\\ \frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&0&0&0 \\\\ \frac{1}{4}&0&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&0&0 \\\\ \frac{1}{4}&0&0&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&0 \\\\ \frac{1}{4}&0&0&0&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4} \\\\ \frac{1}{4}&0&0&0&0&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

where the state space is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.  I actually have two questions, one of which I've already answered and the other I cannot figure out.  Here's the one I've already answered:

*Suppose the chain has been running for a long time and we start watching the chain.  What is the probability that the next three states will be $4$, $5$, $0$ in that order?*

For this problem, I found the invariant probability vector $\pi$.  I then computed

$$\pi(4) * p(4, 5) * p(5, 0) = .013 * \frac{1}{4} * \frac{1}{4} = .0008125.$$

Did I take the right approach to this question?  If not, I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction.

The problem I cannot figure out reads:

*Suppose the chain starts in state $1$.  What is the probability that it reaches state $6$ before reaching state $0$?*

I get the feeling that I will have to compute the $Q$ matrix treating $0$ as an absorbing state, but beyond that, I can't think of what I would do.  Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exercise 1.10 in the second edition of *Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by 
Gregory Lawler. To solve it, use the method described starting in the middle of page 29.
You need to consider both states $0$ and $6$ as absorbing, and use both the $Q$-matrix
 of transition probabilities from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to itself, 
 and the $S$ matrix of transition probabilities from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to $\{0,6\}$.

That is, we have 
$$Q=\pmatrix{1/4&1/4&0&0&0\cr
             1/4&1/4&1/4&0&0\cr
             0&1/4&1/4&1/4&0\cr
             0&0&1/4&1/4&1/4\cr
             0&0&0&1/4&1/4\cr}$$ 
and 
$$S=\pmatrix{1/2&0\cr
             1/4&0\cr
             1/4&0\cr
             1/4&0\cr
             1/4&1/4\cr}.$$

The probability you want is the $(1,6)$ entry in 
the matrix 
$$(I-Q)^{-1}S=\pmatrix{143/144&1/144\cr
                       47/48&1/48\cr
                       17/18&1/18\cr
                       41/48&7/48\cr
                       89/144&55/144}.$$
The columns of this matrix are labelled $0,6$
 while the rows are labelled $1,2,3,4,5$.
The required probability is $1/144$.

Comment: Thanks, Byron.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Incidentally I was able to figure it out when I needed it, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Could you explain why this works?

Comment: Your argument has a problem, states 0 and 6 are not absorbing, that is evident from the transition matrix.

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, I feel like what it's asking is slightly more complicated. What it seems to be asking is, suppose I let this chain run for a while, and then I observe it to be in a state $x$. What is the chance that immediately after this, the chain consecutively visits 4,5 and then 0, in that order. So I would condition on seeing the chain in state $x$, and then sum over the state space. In other words,

$\sum_{x=0}^6\pi(x)*p(x,4)p(4,5)p(5,0)$

This should simplify nicely and you might find a surprise in the answer.

For the second question, let $f(x)$ be the probability a markov chain starting at $x$, hit 6 before 0. In other words, you are interested in $f(0)$. We can come up with the following set of equations:

$\forall x\neq 0,6: \ f(x)=p(x,6)+(1-p(x,6)-p(x,0))\sum_{z\neq \{0,6\}}f(z)$

$f(0)=0$

$f(6)=1$

which gives you a system of six equations for six unknowns (well, two are immediate). Solving this will give you what you desire.

Comment: More intuitive for me compared to the other answer. Thanks!

Comment: For the first part of the answer, what's the difference from the questioner's answer? Since $\pi$ is the stationary distribution, then $\sum_{x=0}^6\pi(x)*p(x,4)=p(4)$, so the answers coincide.