# The probability a Markov Chain never reaches a state

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix, discrete-time

Given a Discrete Time Markov Chain and an initial distribution, how do you find the probability the chain will never reach a state?

For example, an easy DTMC, knowing that it started at state 0, what would be the probability it never reaches state 2?

\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2&0\\1/3&1/3&1/3\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

My attempt: I know how to find the probability of a certain state at a time n, multiplying the initial state by the transition matrix raised to the nth power, so I was thinking I would take 1 minus this time for a sufficiently large n (to find the probability it eventually reaches the certain state), but that wouldn't guarantee the chain had never reached the certain state.

I saw this: [Markov Chain never reaches a state](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608204/markov-chain-never-reaches-a-state)
but it didn't answer the second question.

Comment: Find the probability it *will* reach the final state eventually and then...

Comment: But how would I do that?

Comment: Are you looking for a general strategy to compute this probability, or are you only interested in this probability with respect to the example you provided? If you draw a state transition diagram, its pretty obvious the probability you never encounters state $2$ equals $0$

Comment: I was looking for a general strategy, and gave an example, because it might make sense if explained through an example.

Comment: Have you learned about communication classes and recurrent states?

Comment: Yes, I've learned a bit about them

Comment: So in your example all of the states communicate, so it’s an irreducible Markov chain with finite state space, and all of the states are recurrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finite state chains, the only positive-probability way this can happen is there exists $k$ such that $k$ is reachable from $i$ and $j$ is not reachable from $k$. Then if you hit $k$ before $j$ then you will never reach $j$. Thus in your example this probability is just zero.

Now let $u$ be a column vector so that $u_i$ is the probability to never reach $j$ started from $i$. You want some particular $u_{i_0}$, but it is easier to get $u_{i_0}$ by getting all the $u_i$ together or at least for all $i$ reachable from $i_0$. Let $A$ consist of all $k$ such that $j$ is not reachable from $k$. Finally let $P$ be the transition probability matrix in the row-stochastic convention. Then you have

$$(Pu)_i=u_i \quad i \not \in A \cup \{ j \} \\
u_i=1 \quad i \in A \\
u_j=0.$$

I can give the derivation of this system but it basically follows from using the total probability formula for one step.

Comment: Thanks! This made sense to me.  Rather than thinking of it as probability of never reaching a certain state, it's the probability of reaching an absorbing state.

Comment: @SecondDawn100 It actually is not. In some chains you can reach a communicating class from which you cannot reach $j$ but which does not contain an absorbing state.